# I cloned a hard disk drive to an SSD with EaseUS’s but I did not select: “Optimize for SSD.” Will this cause issues?

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, ssd, clone, easeus-todo-backup

I recently bought a new SSD and cloned my hard drive using EaseUS Todo Backup. However, when I cloned the drive I forgot to select “Optimize for SSD.” There was very little on the hard drive besides for the operating system at the time.

Will it make a difference that I didn’t select “Optimize for SSD” and what does the optimization do exactly?

Should I go ahead and reclone my drive? Am I being paranoid?

Comment: Please see the help section for the tool you used to determine what _"Optimize for SSD"_ does.

Comment: You already have a decent answer. But will give you a friendly bit of practical advice: If this question lingers in your head and you are concerned *and* it’s not too much of a hassle, then my advice is to do it all over: Clone the hard disk to SSD with the “optimize” button checked. Peace of mind is more valuable than efficiency in many cases; tech related and otherwise.

Answer (score 3):

I think you are ok the way it is, have you tried booting from it?

From the [website of EaseUS](https://www.easeus.com/support/todo-backup/clone-a-hard-disk.html):

> ### Advanced clone settings
>
> These advanced settings can help you clone a drive more stably and smoothly in some special case. However, without these advanced settings, EaseUS Todo backup can still give you an exact and intact clone.
>
> **Optimize for SSD** - If the destination disk is an SSD, checking this option will ensure sector alignment in the process.
>
> **Sector by sector clone** - A sector by sector clone ensures that  the destination hard disk/partition is exactly the same as the source hard disk/partition. It will clone all the sectors if the option is checked, even if the sector is blank. As a result, 
>   the target will be equal in size to the disk being cloned after the process. This option is found in the same step where you  choose the destination hard disk/partition both in the 
>   Disk clone and Partition clone wizard.
>
> ***Note***:
>
> *The disk/partition cannot be resized if you choose to clone your disk in the Sector by sector mode.*

Comment: This is a decent answer, but just for reference, I made edits to add a direct link to the website this info came from, and formatted the text so it’s clear it is a quote of content from that website.

Comment: @JakeGould I thought I did enter the site link, thank you for that. If you would like, I can delete it and you can post the answer?

Comment: Nope. This is your answer. I am just explaining how if you post an answer like this, there are ways you should format it.